# How do I get a custom UINavigationItem titleView to be positioned correctly after changing its size?

Tags: ios

I am using a custom `titleView` in my UINavigationItem that contains a UILabel. After changing the text in the UILabel, I then resize the titleView accordingly. However, the UINavigationBar does not reposition the titleView properly. How can I get the navigation bar to update?

Answer (score 0):

After resizing the titleView, do the following:

```
 navigationItem.titleView = myTitleView
 navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
```

Both lines are needed.

Do not bother to implement `sizeThatFits` in your view, as it will have no effect on the repositioning behavior.

Tested in iOS 10.